# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C://abc.png

Tags: jquery

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIL7F.png)atable(jquery) i want to show image in column but it is giving me a error Not allowed to load local resource:even file path is correct

```
var UserTable = $('.Users_Detail').DataTable({
  data: JsonData,
  columns: [{
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return '<input type="radio" name="SelectRow" value="' + row.USER_ID + '"  style="margin-left:15px;" class="CheckedRow">';
      },
    },
    {
      "data": "USER_NAME"
    },
    {
      "data": "CISRMNM"
    },
    {
      "data": "CISRMDESIG"
    },
    {
      "data": "EMAIL_ID"
    },
  ],
  "columnDefs": [{
      "width": "5%",
      "targets": 0
    },
    {
      "targets": 6,
      "data": "img",
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        return '<img  src="C:\\Users\\Images\\tick.png"/ >'
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load local resources into your web application you need to place them into your server directory first try saving all the resources into the application directory and then load them using relative path.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp